# Meteor Collection blank outside isClient

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2

I am using Collection2 and Autoform for an app.

I have a `select` with options pulled out of a `collection` of states for addresses.

My schemas are declared outside the isServer/isClient blocks.

```
var Schemas = {};
Schemas.addresses = new SimpleSchema({
  state_id: {
    type: Meteor.ObjectID,
    autoform: {
      options: function () {
        console.log(states.find().fetch());
        return states.find().map(function (c) {
          return {label: c.name, value: c._id};
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
people = new Meteor.Collection("people");
Schemas.people =    new SimpleSchema({
  address:{
    type: [Schemas.addresses],
    optional: true
  }
});
people.attachSchema(Schemas.people);
states = new Meteor.Collection("states");
```

in the isClient block:

```
Meteor.subscribe("states");
```

in the isServer block:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  Meteor.publish("states", function () {
    return states.find();
  });
});
```

and finally my template:

```
<template name="createPerson">
  {{> quickForm collection="people" type="insert"}}
</template>
```

You'll see I even added in a `console.log` in the schema autoform options function call, which returns a big empty `[]`. If I place this same `console.log` outside the schema declaration or in the isClient/isServer blocks I get the expected array of states.

What have I missed that would cause this collection to return empty?

Thanks

Comment: subscriptions are async, make sure it returns before you need it, I can't really tell if that's the case...

Comment: @MattK I'm going down the same thought process, but this is called through a user action. Waiting some time before taking that action to call the template doesn't help...

Comment: The schema isn't created on a user process, take out all the logic from the schema & put the fetch in a helper (or rendered) See example http://autoform.meteor.com/select